# display Laravel backend stored image on angular front-end

Tags: angular, laravel

I want to display image in frontend (Angular) , that image stored in Laravel backend.I already try.

Component.html

```
 <img src="https://localhost:8000/images/storage/app/avatars/6.1588776952IMG_9539"/> 
 <div class="mb-4">
 <img  class="img" [src]="imgUrl">
 </div>
```

Laravel Api Route

```
 Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
 {
 $file = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get($filename);
 return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
 });
```

Comment: did you run `php artisan storage:link` first. Run it and try this `<img src='{{ asset('storage/avatars/6.1588776952IMG_9539') }}'/>`. also make sure you are giving the extension of the image too. In your case you are not giving image extension in the path.

Comment: Please check this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-get-image-from-laravel-and-show-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command line.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: i run it . what is next ?

Comment: Please run your project.

Comment: i run , it still the same problem , by the way i'm using angular + laravel